# Starting OVER.About to sacrifice a good laptop to my cause....Need Incantations... I mean "Advice"!

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have been on this road for about a month, and have hit some roadblocks, So here is my next thought, I have a laptop-Dell Inspiron  N5110 I5 2430,8Gb ram, that is about to go to a dual boot world. What installations should I be looking at for a smooth start into ROS/Moveit. It is my daily coder but, this project has grown enough to risk what I have. Can't quite give up the win10 install yet..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254874/starting-over.about-to-sacrifice-a-good-laptop-to-my-cause....need-incantations...--i-mean-%22advice%22!/) by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2017-02-16

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:
Could you please use some tags that actually fit with your question? Just to make this more discoverable for potential future visitors. Thanks.

**Comment by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on 2017-02-17**:
Have tried multiple times to retag and edit this.... doesn't seem to work.

**Comment by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on 2017-02-17**:
wiped the laptop and installed ubuntu 16.04 /ros kinetic/ moveit  all in just a few hours, completely different experience, compared with the last month.... Already further ahead then I was yesterday... Thanks for the information and assistance.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-17**:
Good to hear.

re: experience: yes, as I told you in one of your previous questions, you basically selected one of the tough(est) deployments and started learning ROS together with your deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that it is really hard to advice users on these matters. Much depends on your specific use of packages, OS and (robot) hw. But, as of 2017-02-16:

- I think the (Ubuntu Trusty; ROS Indigo) combination (both `amd64`) still has the largest set of packages build by the buildfarm. Trusty and ROS Indigo are supported till May 2019 ([wiki/Distributions](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions)).
- If you would be ok with a little more building from sources (as also for Indigo you'll occasionaly run into packages that don't have a binary distributed), then Kinetic on Ubuntu Xenial would be a good choice. Supported till May 2021 (again: [wiki/Distributions](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions)).

In general: the community is moving to Xenial/Kinetic, so all development will be moving there as well. Trusty/Indigo is an LTS release, so should remain supported, but developers may decide to put their packages in *maintenance* mode on that distribution. New features would go into Kinetic in those cases.

Note that I obviously cannot determine beforehand whether any Linux distribution will work properly with your hardware. You should search around a bit for user experiences with your particular hw / laptop.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2